# Issue with AES encrypting a 0x00 char

Tags: c, encryption, aes

I'm currently working on a program that encrypt a file with AES-128 (with tiny-aes-c). I'm having a problem with the first array that contain \0 :

```
uint8_t in[16] = {0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d, 0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52};
uint8_t key[16] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
uint8_t iv[16] = { 0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xf7, 0xf8, 0xf9, 0xfa, 0xfb, 0xfc, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xff };

struct AES_ctx ctx;
AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, key, iv);
AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer(&ctx, in, strlen((char*)in));
printf("\nENCODED:      %s", (char*)in);
/*Another print for hex values*/
```

As expected, only the left part is encrypted and the rest disappear. How should I procede to correct this ? Thank you.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are using to call the encryption function.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `strlen(in)` which counts up to first nul byte (0x00), and in this case it returns 8 rather than the full length of the buffer (16).

To correct, determine the length of the buffer by other means. Here you already know that it's 16. You *may* use `sizeof(in)` here, e.g.:

```
uint8_t in[16] = {0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d, 0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52};
uint8_t key[16] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
uint8_t iv[16] = { 0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xf7, 0xf8, 0xf9, 0xfa, 0xfb, 0xfc, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xff };

struct AES_ctx ctx;
AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, key, iv);
AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer(&ctx, in, sizeof(in));
```

but this won't work if you rewrite the code for a variable length array. In that case you should pass the length as an extra parameter.

Comment: Indeed, this was a very stupid error of me. Sorry for this and thank you very much.

Comment: Please update your answer with a version of code using the `sizeof(in)` so that future programmers can come here and see working code immediately.